# Visual Studio Add-in: SVN vs CVS

Tags: visual-studio, svn, cvs, add-in

I have a CVS add-in to Visual Studio. The add-in writes to the output window everything I do (commiting, editing, etc.).
I built a macro that takes the output window and uses it to my own purpose.

Now I moved to SVN, and I use the VisualSVN as add-in to the Visual Studio. But there is no SVN add-in that writes to the VS' output window.

Is there anything that can help me do that?

Thanks,
Oded.

Answer (score 2):

There is a plug-in named AnkhSVN available on Collabnet, is one of the best add-on for Visual Studio for SVN client.

It is available at http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/

Comment: Does AnkhSVN write to the output window in VS ?

Answer (score 0):

[Tam Tam CVS](http://www.daveswebsite.com/software/tamtam/)  seems to do exactly what you need: